Question about the image of a morphism
Let $C$ be a coherent category, and $X_1,..., X_n$ subobjects of an object $X$ such that $X_i \wedge X_j = \varnothing$ for $i \neq j$. Let also $f_i :X_i \rightarrow Y$ by morphisms in $C$, and denote by $\Gamma(f_i)$ the graph of $f_i$ as a subobject of $X \times Y$ for $i =1,..., n$.
Now, consider $Z:= \Gamma(f_1) \lor \cdots \lor \Gamma(f_n)$ as a subobject of $X \times Y$. I would like to prove that the image of the composition $Z \rightarrow X \times Y \xrightarrow{\pi_X} X$ is contained in $X_1 \lor \cdots \lor X_n$, as occurs in $\mathbf{Set}$.
Is it true? Could you give me a hint for proof?

What have you tried? This seems to be immediate from the definitions? How to ask a good question
